# Symphonia .NET component generator not registering

Tags: .net

I'm using the [Symphonia](http://www.apollo.gr/deve/News/news.asp?pid=132) EDI Designer, and trying to generate .NET assemblies, but the button that lets me create .NET assemblies doesn't show up.

What do I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so after some further research I discovered that the .NET component generator COM DLL needed to be registered.  It's the DLL in symphonia\edi\designer\components.net component generator\symphonia.net component generator.dll.

Just registering it with `regsvr32` worked great.  I think that the symphonia3net.dll also needs to be in the [GAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Assembly_Cache), but I am not sure.

And on my Windows 7 box, at some point before I fixed it I also fixed a registry key that had the wrong path pointing to the .NET component generator DLL.  I know that's not necessary on a Windows XP box.  This key was at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Orion\Symphonia\3.8\EDI\EDI Designer\Plugins\NET Generator\FilePath`.

Answer (score 0):

No symphonia3net.dll does not need to be in the GAC, once it is registered the key should point to the correct place.

You also need to have the .Net Framework 1.1 installed prior to registering.